# PowerShell - Invoke-WebRequest - How to use -Form option

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I get an error message when I use the 'FORM option with Invoke-WebRequest powershell utility.
When I use help on the Invoke-WebRequest, I don't see the -FORM option listed.
There is a Microsoft help document that shows an Example 6 with the -FORM option.

QUESTION - Is there something additional I need that supports the -FORM option for the PowerShell
Invoke-WebRequest utility?
COMMENT - The PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest utility works fine for downloading a file.

Using PS version 5.1 on Windows 10.

Here's the script and error message.

```
$Uri = 'http://xxxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx:8080/upload/upload.php'
$Form = @{
    file = Get-Item -Path 'C:\temp\xxxxxxx.pdf'
    nmbr = 'xxxxxxx'
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form
```

```
------------------ ERROR MESSAGE -----------------------
```

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Form'.
At line:6 char:42
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form
+                                                    ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :         
      NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4#-form) state with respect to `-Form`: "This feature was added in PowerShell 6.1.0."; in other words: you can only use this parameter in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thanks for the doc reference. You are correct. I did not catch that.